# Sum duration of overlapping periods with priority by excluding the overlap itself

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an R code and I am trying to rewrite it in PostgreSQL that feeds grafana dashboard. I do have the basics so I am almost done with the other parts of the script but what I am trying to accomplish now in PostgreSQL is beyond my league. I see very similar solved issues on StackOverflow but I can't seem to get them to work for me. Here are some links with code that I was trying to adapt

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54370027/7885817
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44139381/7885817
I applogize for the repetitive issue that I post.
Any help is highly appreciated!

So, my issue is:
I have messages with overlapping timestamps. These messages have **priorities**: **A** and **B** (A is more important), **start time** and **end ime**.

Strictly speaking: I would like to sum the durations for A and B
BUT if there is an overlap I want to find the duration between the first Start Time and the last End Time of messages with priority A and the same for messages with priority B. And if a A message overlaps with a B message I want to split this duration at the End time of A message, till that point the duration of B message is allocated to A.
I made a visual to support my cryptic explanations and simplified version of my data:

```
CREATE TABLE activities(
    id int,
    name text,
    start timestamp,
    "end" timestamp
);

INSERT INTO activitiesVALUES
(1, 'A', '2018-01-09 17:00:00', '2018-01-09 20:00:00'),
(2, 'A', '2018-01-09 18:00:00', '2018-01-09 20:30:00'),
(3, 'B', '2018-01-09 19:00:00', '2018-01-09 21:30:00'),
(4, 'B', '2018-01-09 22:00:00', '2018-01-09 23:00:00');

SELECT * FROM activities;
```

[image]

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
My original solution was not correct.  The consolidation of ranges cannot be handled in a regular window.  I confused myself by using the same name, `trange`, forgetting that the window is over the source rows rather than the result rows.  Please see the updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/138f2/2) with the full query as well as an added record to illustrate the problem.

You can simplify the overlapping requirement as well as identifying gaps and islands using [PostgreSQL range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html).

The following query is intentionally verbose to show each step of the process.  A number of steps can be combined.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/06c0a7/1)

First, add an inclusive `[start, end]` range to each record.

```
with add_ranges as (
  select id, name, tsrange(start, "end", '[]') as t_range
    from activities
), 

 id | name |                    t_range                    
----+------+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | A    | ["2018-01-09 17:00:00","2018-01-09 20:00:00"]
  2 | A    | ["2018-01-09 18:00:00","2018-01-09 20:30:00"]
  3 | B    | ["2018-01-09 19:00:00","2018-01-09 21:30:00"]
  4 | B    | ["2018-01-09 22:00:00","2018-01-09 23:00:00"]
(4 rows)
```

Identify overlapping ranges as determined by the `&&` operator and mark the beginning of new islands with a `1`.

```
mark_islands as (
  select id, name, t_range,
         case
           when t_range && lag(t_range) over w then 0
           else 1
         end as new_range
    from add_ranges
  window w as (partition by name order by t_range)
),

 id | name |                    t_range                    | new_range 
----+------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------
  1 | A    | ["2018-01-09 17:00:00","2018-01-09 20:00:00"] |         1
  2 | A    | ["2018-01-09 18:00:00","2018-01-09 20:30:00"] |         0
  3 | B    | ["2018-01-09 19:00:00","2018-01-09 21:30:00"] |         1
  4 | B    | ["2018-01-09 22:00:00","2018-01-09 23:00:00"] |         1
(4 rows)
```

Number the groups based on the sum of the `new_range` within `name`.

```
group_nums as (
  select id, name, t_range, 
         sum(new_range) over (partition by name order by t_range) as group_num
    from mark_islands
),

 id | name |                    t_range                    | group_num 
----+------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------
  1 | A    | ["2018-01-09 17:00:00","2018-01-09 20:00:00"] |         1
  2 | A    | ["2018-01-09 18:00:00","2018-01-09 20:30:00"] |         1
  3 | B    | ["2018-01-09 19:00:00","2018-01-09 21:30:00"] |         1
  4 | B    | ["2018-01-09 22:00:00","2018-01-09 23:00:00"] |         2
```

Group by `name, group_num` to get the total time spent on the island as well as a complete `t_range` to be used in overlap deduction.

```
islands as (
  select name,
         tsrange(min(lower(t_range)), max(upper(t_range)), '[]') as t_range,
         max(upper(t_range)) - min(lower(t_range)) as island_time_interval
    from group_nums
   group by name, group_num
),

 name |                    t_range                    | island_time_interval 
------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------------
 A    | ["2018-01-09 17:00:00","2018-01-09 20:30:00"] | 03:30:00
 B    | ["2018-01-09 19:00:00","2018-01-09 21:30:00"] | 02:30:00
 B    | ["2018-01-09 22:00:00","2018-01-09 23:00:00"] | 01:00:00
(3 rows)
```

For the requirement to count overlap time between `A` messages and `B` messages, find occurrences of when an `A` message overlaps a `B` message, and use the `*` intersect operator to find the intersection.

```
priority_overlaps as (
  select b.name, a.t_range * b.t_range as overlap_range
    from islands a
    join islands b
      on a.t_range && b.t_range
     and a.name = 'A' and b.name != 'A'
),

 name |                 overlap_range                 
------+-----------------------------------------------
 B    | ["2018-01-09 19:00:00","2018-01-09 20:30:00"]
(1 row)
```

Sum the total time of each overlap by `name`.

```
overlap_time as (
  select name, sum(upper(overlap_range) - lower(overlap_range)) as total_overlap_interval
    from priority_overlaps
   group by name
),

 name | total_overlap_interval 
------+------------------------
 B    | 01:30:00
(1 row)
```

Calculate the total time for each `name`.

```
island_times as (
  select name, sum(island_time_interval) as name_time_interval
    from islands
   group by name
)

 name | name_time_interval 
------+--------------------
 B    | 03:30:00
 A    | 03:30:00
(2 rows)
```

Join the total time for each `name` to adjustments from the `overlap_time` CTE, and subtract the adjustment for the final `duration` value.

```
select i.name,
       i.name_time_interval - coalesce(o.total_overlap_interval, interval '0') as duration
  from island_times i
  left join overlap_time o
    on o.name = i.name
;

 name | duration 
------+----------
 B    | 02:00:00
 A    | 03:30:00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: that's insane!!! :) Thank you very very much and for the comments - super many thnaks!  -All the best!

Comment: @eyei Sorry, but there is a flaw in my consolidation CTE, `mark_islands`.  I am working on a fix to it, and I will update my answer.  This shows the error:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/138f2/1

Comment: oh, yes, that's an important one. Would you give me your PayPal later so I could buy you at least a beer! Thank you for continue working on this!

Comment: @eyei  Not necessary on the PayPal.  Sorry about the mistake.  I feel I owe you a beer, so maybe we're even?  I added a link to the query in a new SQL Fiddle and updated the comments in the answer.

Comment: :) well, I can't thank you enough then!  -All the best

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  To solve this, find where the "islands" begin and then aggregate.  So, to get the islands:

```
select a.name, min(start) as startt, max("end") as endt
from (select a.*,
             count(*) filter (where prev_end is null or prev_end < start) over (partition by name order by start, id) as grp
      from (select a.*,
                   max("end") over (partition by name
                                    order by start, id
                                    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                   ) as prev_end
            from activities a
           ) a
     ) a
group by name, grp;
```

The next step is just to aggregate again:

```
with islands as (
      select a.name, min(start) as startt, max("end") as endt
      from (select a.*,
                   count(*) filter (where prev_end is null or prev_end < start) over (partition by name order by start, id) as grp
            from (select a.*,
                         max("end") over (partition by name
                                          order by start, id
                                          rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                         ) as prev_end
                  from activities a
                 ) a
           ) a
      group by name, grp
     )
select name, sum(endt - startt)
from islands i
group by name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fce18609d669235312d5a6e448421c2b) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that this uses a cumulative trailing maximum to define the overlaps.  This is the most general method for determining overlaps.  I think this will work on all edge cases, including:

```
1----------2---2----3--3-----1
```

It also handles ties on the start time.

Comment: wow! thank you very much! gaps-and-islands - never heard of. I run the code in db fiddle but the B messages should be 2 hours instead of 3 h and 30 min. is there an option to overwrite the start of B message with the end of A message if B has an overlap with A?

Comment: @eyei . . . I would suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: I asked a new question but referred to this thread. Thank you very much for your time! I truly appreciate it! I am going to close the question later.