# Overwrite start time of B message with the end time of A message if B overlaps A

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is the second thread of an issue I am having. here is part one: [Sum duration of overlapping periods with priority by excluding the overlap itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62953977/7885817)
I didn't state the title as accurately as possible so the issue could be solved in one thread. Many thanks to Gordon Linoff for bringing me closer to the finish line.

I wouldn't duplicate the content of the initial thread, please check it here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62954132/7885817

My new question is:
Is there an option to overwrite the start time of B message with the end time of A message if B overlaps with A?

I have messages with overlapping timestamps. These messages have priorities: A and B (A is more important), start time and end ime.

Strictly speaking: I would like to sum the durations for A and B BUT if there is an overlap I want to find the duration between the first Start Time and the last End Time of messages with priority A and the same for messages with priority B. And if a A message overlaps with a B message I want to split this duration at the End time of A message, till that point the duration of B message is allocated to A. I made a visual to support my cryptic explanations and simplified version of my data:

```
CREATE TABLE activities(
    id int,
    name text,
    start timestamp,
    "end" timestamp
);

INSERT INTO activitiesVALUES
(1, 'A', '2018-01-09 17:00:00', '2018-01-09 20:00:00'),
(2, 'A', '2018-01-09 18:00:00', '2018-01-09 20:30:00'),
(3, 'B', '2018-01-09 19:00:00', '2018-01-09 21:30:00'),
(4, 'B', '2018-01-09 22:00:00', '2018-01-09 23:00:00');

SELECT * FROM activities;
```

[image]

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fce18609d669235312d5a6e448421c2b

```
with islands as (
      select a.name, min(start) as startt, max("end") as endt
      from (select a.*,
                   count(*) filter (where prev_end is null or prev_end < start) over (partition by name order by start, id) as grp
            from (select a.*,
                         max("end") over (partition by name
                                          order by start, id
                                          rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                         ) as prev_end
                  from activities a
                 ) a
           ) a
      group by name, grp
     )
select name, sum(endt - startt)
from islands i
group by name;
```

Comment: There are more possible scenarios. Such as: B is *contained* in A, etc.

Comment: Could you, please, provide full example? Yes I can go back and forth to see what is going on, but to me that is waste of time. Just put sample data, with all corner cases, and sample try.

Comment: In such case, B shouldn't be calculated at all. A has the priority.

Comment: Code provided. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would use `range` type for that. Please look [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html), operations are described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE).

Here is my try:

```
CREATE TABLE activities(
    id int,
    name text,
    period tsrange
);

INSERT INTO activities VALUES
(1, 'A', '[2018-01-09 17:00:00, 2018-01-09 20:00:00]'::tsrange),
(2, 'A', '[2018-01-09 18:00:00, 2018-01-09 20:30:00]'::tsrange),
(3, 'B', '[2018-01-09 19:00:00, 2018-01-09 21:30:00]'::tsrange),
(4, 'B', '[2018-01-09 22:00:00, 2018-01-09 23:00:00]'::tsrange);
```

To see overlapping entries (comparing ids gives single answer):

```
select * 
from
 activities a1,
 activities a2
where
 a1.id < a2.id
 and a1.period && a2.period;
```

I'm not sure if got you right. Anyway - overlapping, with different names, and `a2` extending `a1`:

```
select * 
from
 activities a1,
 activities a2
where
 a1.id < a2.id and a1.name <> a2.name
 and a1.period && a2.period and a1.period &< a2.period;
```

Is it close enough?

Comment: it seems close. but the output is for B 19:00:00- 21:30:00 twice represented. and the 22-23 is missing.